# If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m<n$, and $AA^T = I_m$, what are the eigenvalues of $3I_n - A^TA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

> If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m<n$, and $AA^T = I_m$, what are the eigenvalues of $3I_n - A^TA$?

How can I start? I know the eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$, but how do I find the eigenvalues of $A^TA$?

Comment: $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non zero eigenvalues. The eigenvalues of the matrix $C+tI$ are $c+t$, where $c$ is an eigenvalue of $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $3I_n-A^TA$ is the same as saying that $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA-3I_n$ or, as well, that
$$
A^TA-3I_n+\lambda I_n=A^TA-(3-\lambda)I_n
$$
is not invertible. In other words, the eigenvalues you are looking for are of the form $3-\mu$, where $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Now suppose $\mu\ne0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and let $v$ be an eigenvector. Then $A^TAv=\mu v$ (in particular $Av\ne0$), so also
$$
(AA^T)(Av)=\mu(Av)
$$
so $Av$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^T$ relative to $\mu$. Since $AA^T=I_m$, we conclude $\mu=1$.

Since $A^TA$ is $n\times n$ and $n>m$, we also know that $0$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Two things I don t understand: Why is the eigenvalue of $3I_n -A^T.A$ the same as $A.A^T-3I_n$ ? Shouldn t it be the opposite?  I also don't get the last line.

Comment: @Gloomy Which ones? I fixed the last $AA^T$ into $A^TA$.

Comment: (Sorry, was writing from my smartphone, posted by mistake before finishing)

Comment: @Gloomy You're right, I'll fix it. Since $n>m$ and the rank of $A^TA$ is at most $m$, then $A^TA$ is not invertible and has $0$ as eigenvalue.